# Docker 'data only container' being shut down

Tags: docker, containers, persistent-storage

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.  Plenty of tutorials state that having a data only container is how you achieve persistent data in docker.  What I don't understand however is that the data only seems to be persistent as long as the data only container exists.  When it is shut down and restarted, the data simply disappears.

Considering that no system will have a 100% up time, and I want the contents of a long term database to persist beyond physical system restarts and such.  How do I properly persist data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Plenty of tutorials state that having a data only container is how you achieve persistent data in docker.

Note that with recent versions of Docker this is no longer the case; volumes are now "first class" citizens and can be created/deleted/etc with the `docker volume` command.  This means you can create a persistent data volume by running:

```
$ docker volume create --name myvolume
```

And later on you can attach to it like this:

```
$ docker run -v myvolume:/data ...
```

> What I don't understand however is that the data only seems to be persistent as long as the data only container exists.

It would help if you were to include in your question information about how you created your data-only container.  Note that a data-only container does *not* have to be "running" to be useful; it simply has to exist.  So, for example, I could create a data-only container like this:

```
$ docker run -v /data --name datacontainer  busybox true
```

That will, of course, run `/bin/true` and then exit immediately:

```
$ docker ps -a
47568a43d386        busybox                     "true"                   7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                        datacontainer
```

But even though the container has exited I can make use of the volume in a new container:

```
$ docker run -it --volumes-from datacontainer busybox sh
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/tank-docker--vol
                      83844100   2398688  81445412   3% /data
```

This mechanism is what you would use to get persistent volumes in Docker earlier than 1.10 (1.9, maybe?), but is no longer necessary because of the `docker volume` command.

Comment: Just to add to this for anyone who is struggling in the way I was.  Your data only container creates a volume, which has a generated name (4488845jgjg3 for example).  When you next instance up the container, it creates a second volume with a different name.  Both volumes exist on the host machine, but unless you reference them by id, you don't automatically get access to them.

Comment: That's why you give the data container a name, and access the volumes using `--volumes-from` (so that you don't need to worry about the id of the individual volumes).